# Problema com importação do HREF

Tags: html, css

Não sei explicar direito o que está acontecendo com o meu código, pois sou iniciante em programação. Mas é o seguinte: fiz uma importação com href para meu arquivo css; para dentro do html:

```
<html>

<head>

    <title> RPG in Browser </title>

    <link href="Componentes/CSS/O Começo.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

e uma outra importação href para uma imagem que eu quero que clique e direcione para outra página:

```
<tr>

<td> <a href="Componentes/HTML/Arqueiro/Página 01/HTML/Página 01.html">

<img src="Componentes/Imagens/O Começo/Arqueiro.jpg" id="ImagemClasse"> </a> </td>
```

só que a página buga e não importa o arquivo css e tudo fica em branco. Porém quando eu tiro o segundo href a página volta ao normal, com a configuração css normal, porém sem a imagem encaminhando para a página que eu quero. Gostaria de saber se eu consigo fazer duas importações href ou se eu posso fazer somente uma no código todo e como eu resolvo esse problema.

Código HTML:

```
<html>

<head>

    <title> RPG in Browser </title>

    <link href="Componentes/CSS/O Começo.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

<div id="TabelaCentral">

    <table id="Tabela">

        <tr>

            <td id="Classe"> <b id="Font35"> Arqueiro </b> </td>

            <td id="Classe"> <b id="Font35"> Guerreiro </b> </td>

            <td id="Classe"> <b id="Font35"> Mago </b> </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td> <a href="Componentes/HTML/Arqueiro/Página 01/HTML/Página 01.html">

            <img src="Componentes/Imagens/O Começo/Arqueiro.jpg" id="ImagemClasse"> </a> </td> 


            <td> <a href="Página 03.html">

            <img src="Componentes/Imagens/O Começo/Guerreiro.jpg" id="ImagemClasse"> </a> </td> 


            <td> <a href="Página 04.html">

            <img src="Componentes/Imagens/O Começo/Mago.jpg" id="ImagemClasse"> </a> </td>

        </tr>   

    </table>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Código CSS:

```
body {

background-image: url("../Imagens/O Começo/Background - Main.jpg");

background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%;

}

#TabelaCentral {

    margin-top:125; align: center; 
}

#Tabela {

    width: 350; height: 250; margin: auto;

}

#Classe {

    height: 75; width: 200; text-align: center; background-color: white;

}

#Font35 {

    font-size: 35;

}

#ImagemClasse {

    height: 300; width: 200; align: center;

}
```

Desculpe os erros de formatação do código, ainda estou aprendendo a usar a plataforma.

Comment: Perry, coloca o código completo, por favor, pois não deveria ocorrer erro, talvez algum outro item está gerando esse problema.

Comment: pronto, coloquei

Comment: pra adicionar informção pra vocce, tem um erro conceitual importante nesse codigo, vc usou ID igual em varios objetos, quando o id deve ser unico, mude por exemplo id="Classe" ara class="Classe" e no css troque #Classe por .Classe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

troque `<link href="Componentes/CSS/O Começo.css" rel="stylesheet">` por `<link href="Componentes/CSS/ocomeco.css" rel="stylesheet">`, altere o nome do arquivo para `ocomeco.css`, altere também qualquer link que você tenha colocado um espaço entre as palavras, se for necessário colocar "o começo" coloque dessa forma `o-comeco.css`, preferencialmente sem o ç, em uma pagina utf-8 ele é reconhecido, mais pode dar alguma falha na requisição em alguns servidores, apesar de que em uma pagina normal de um post, você poderia usa-lo sem grandes problemas, desde que ela esteja registrada dessa forma.

veja se funciona e me dá um retorno, se tiver dado certo, marque como resolvido : )

Comment: Deu certo sim, obrigado.

Comment: que bom, qualquer coisa volte a postar!

Answer (score 1):

Para corrigir esse problema, tente acrescentar à pagina HTML a tag:

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Assim, você poderá utilizar os caracteres disponíveis na nossa língua.Caso o erro persista, tente alterar o nome de sua página CSS.